# Parse date from JSON to Java

Tags: java, android, date, android-studio

I am calling t a web service to retrieve dates. These dates come in this format

`"2018-01-24T05:00:00.000Z"`

Now, I need to parse that to more legible, something like `"dd-MM-YYYY"`, e.g. `1-24-2018`.

How can I do it?

I'm using Android Studio and a read about Instant but it requires minSdkVersion 26 and is set to 15 what is perfect for me right now.

Comment: Can you post more examples of the format, it's not clear what it actually signifies

Comment: You are asking: 1) how to parse a date, and 2) how to format a date. Both questions have been answered a gazillion times, and all you have to do is **research**, aka a web search for those two questions. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: I believe you *can* use `Instant`on API level 15 through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). And that you *should* consider doing so. In that case import `org.threeten.bp.Instant` and other date-time classes from the same package with subpackages.

Comment: @GursheeshSingh, it’s clearly ISO 8601, so well-defined. The format can for instance be descirbed as by [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT).

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom deserializer for JSON for dates.

You can easily parse them to Java Date object

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("2018-01-24T05:00:00.000Z");
```

for more details see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this....

I did this in Eclipse....

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    String jsonDate = "2018-01-24T05:00:00.000Z";

    String[] split = jsonDate.split("-");

    System.out.println(split[0]);
    System.out.println(split[1]);
    System.out.println(split[2].substring(0, 2));

    String month = split[1].toString();
    String day = split[2].substring(0, 2).toString();
    String year = split[0].toString();

    System.out.println(month + "-" + day + "-" + year);
}
```

output

> 2018
>
> 01
>
> 24
>
> 01-24-2018

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

private String formatDateFromString (String dateString) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS" );
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        return "";
    }
```